# Detect Duplicate data input on different dates

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have the following data that will be input everyday, Column A = Input Date, Column B = Model #. I am just wondering if I could do a conditional formatting for detecting the same models that is inserted on different days.

[image]

For instance, on Date (1/1), I input two A's and one B, since those two A's are inserted on the same day, there is no alarm. But when I insert another A on a different date (1/2), is it possible to set up a conditional formatting for this duplicate entry?

I did try the following code, but then it applies to all three A's.

=countif(B:B,B1)>1

Do I need to combine both column A [Date] and Column B[Model #] so that whenever another A is inserted on a different date, then the conditional formatting is applied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below formula `Validation` (Select B:B as range)

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,B:B,0))=A1
```

Or Use `Conditional Formatting` with the below formula (Select B:B as range)

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,B:B,0))<>A1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use conditional formatting with custom formula.

1. First select range A2:B1000
2. Go to Format → Conditional Formatting
3. Use custom formula

This formula should work, paste it as your formula:

`=NOT(ISNA(FILTER($A$2:A,$A$2:$A<>$A2,$B$2:$B=$B2)))`

The result is similiar to this:

[image]